# Force Close Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, webforms

I have a page (let's say page1) that open the page2 using:

```
showModalDialog(page2, '', 'dialogWidth:55em; dialogHeight:50em; status:0');
```

I am facing 2 problems (in this post i am going to write the first one):

**1**) when i want to close the second page using javascript code it always asks me that the page is trying to close itself do i want to allow that or no. I want to force close it without asking me anything. I have tried the following:

```
function CloseSelection(id) {
    window.opener = "page1"
    window.returnValue = id;
    window.close();
}
```

And in the Form tag `target="_self"`. But nothing happened, the popup keeps on showing.

can anyone help me please?

Comment: _"And in the Form tag"_ - What form is that? In which browser(s) do you have this problem? (Also, why are you setting `window.opener`?)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to set the **window.opener** as it is set by default to the object of opener page.
On Page2 the code will be:

```
function CloseSelection(id) {    
   window.returnValue = id;
   window.close();
}
```

On Page1

```
var returnVal = showModalDialog("page2.html", '', 'dialogWidth:55em; dialogHeight:50em; status:0');
// here returnVal will contain the data which is return by page2
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can not force the window to open in a new window. It might work in some browsers but not all.

In order to close a window you can do this:

```
// open
var win = window.open("someurlgoeshere");
// close
win.close();
```

I believe you only get the "are u sure you wish the leave this page" message if the window itself tries to close itself (`window.close()`)